# How can I generate peer admin card for hyperledger fabric business network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have created a fabric network with one organization of three peers and three orderers. Im trying to deploy business network archieve(.bna) via composer cli. For deployment, we must have peer admin card of that particular network. So please let me know how to create peer admin card for the network? And also please explain what exactly the peer admin card do?? Thanks!!

Comment: Peer admin card is not specific to a business network, it is used to manage the peers and other components. You want the network admin card instead to manage the business network. That card is produced when you install the bna.

Comment: So you mean tha "we are able to deploy business network without peer admin card??"

Comment: No, I misunderstood your question at first. have you created a peer admin card before using createPeerAdminCard.sh as in https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/installing/development-tools.html. you can use that same card to deploy and install business networks, during the installation another network card is created, that one is specific to the business network.

Comment: Yeah exactly. But that admin card  is limited for that network only. What Im trying to tell you is I created my own network with multi peers. So it makes no sense for using ./createPeerAdminCard.sh script for this network. It will create card for the predefined network of single org right??

Comment: you have a little confusion in understanding the concepts. the "Peer Admin Card" can be used to deploy multiple "Business Networks". "Business Network" is just another name for "smart contract" or "chaincode" or decentralized application. you use "Peer Admin Card" that you created using ./createPeerAdminCard.sh to deploy Business Network (bna files or apps) into the network of peers you have created. the "Network admin card" is something different, it is specific to the Business Network application used for management.

Comment: Thats what exactly Im thinking bro. No confusion at all. Listen clearly forget about fabric-dev-servers repository. I have my own fabric network of one organization with three peers and 3 orderes. Im not talking about smartcontract . For now I wanted deploy chain code or (business network or smart contract) on to that three peer fabric network. Are you still with me?? So in order to deploy (.bna) we must provide peer admin card  of that three peer network . Once deployed, we are able import network card that is quite other thing.as u said, it is helpful for managing and restarting chaincode ti

Comment: If that the case just change ./createPeerAdminCard.sh according to your needs all you have to do is to change the connection.json file which is embedded in the sh file and add your other peers and orderers. Also, specify the correct private key locations. if you look into https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-tools/blob/master/packages/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/createPeerAdminCard.sh I am talking about line 60 and 61.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for.. I thought there is cli tool to auto generate connection profile. Then on we can create admin card. I appreciate your efforts towards this question. Thank you @RaniDevpr

Comment: you are welcome, the first card only needs to be done this way, the others will be generated automatically with the same connection profile.